# Adding two or more google maps on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to show several google maps on my page, I have tried to change function name but with no luck, does anybody knows where must I change a name of varibles. Becuase I have tried to change the `initialize` function to `initialize2` but I think I have to change this name in more places, as I have several addresses

Here is my code so far

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            /* google maps */

            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

            var map;
            function initialize() {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = $('#map-eindhoven').text(); /* change the map-input to your address */
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-eindhoven'), mapOptions);

                if (geocoder) {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                                    {
                                        content: address,
                                        map: map,
                                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                    });

                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                    map: map,
                                    title: address
                                });

                            } else {
                                alert("No results found");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


            var map;
            function initialize2() {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = $('#map-rotterdam').text(); /* change the map-input to your address */
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-rotterdam'), mapOptions);

                if (geocoder) {
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                                    {
                                        content: address,
                                        map: map,
                                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                    });

                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                    map: map,
                                    title: address
                                });

                            } else {
                                alert("No results found");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize2);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your second initialize with this:

```
        var map2;
        function initialize2() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = $('#map-rotterdam').text(); /* change the map-input to your address */
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-rotterdam'), mapOptions);

            if (geocoder) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                            map2.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: address,
                                map: map2,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            });

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                map: map2,
                                title: address
                            });

                        } else {
                            alert("No results found");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize2);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QLk6c/2/)

Comment: No that does not owrk, on first element i got marker, and o second i got map :(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to setCenter on map2, updated answer - try again

Comment: No problems, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-eindhoven'), mapOptions);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-rotterdam'), mapOptions);
```

`map` variable goes to the ready function's scope and is rewritten after the second map initialization.

You should add var statement before creating instance, not before function.
Read this for more information.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0):

google.map.Map() is a object <=> you save array object to validate map. and 1 item to focus 1 tag map in your website

```
var map = new Array();

    map[1] =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-a'), mapOptions);
    map[2] =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-b'), mapOptions);
```

Comment: google.map.Map() is a object <=> you save array object to validate map. and 1 item to focus 1 tag map in your website.